how can I use local llama3 to replace openai to call generate_qa_embedding_pairs?
how can I use local llama3 to replace openai to call generate_qa_embedding_pairs?
model = "gpt-4o"
llm = OpenAI(
    model=model,
    api_key=get_openai_key(),
    api_base=get_openai_url(),
)

train_dataset = generate_qa_embedding_pairs(
   llm=llm, nodes=train_nodes
)

